# From TCL use a variable in sqlite IN statement

Tags: sqlite, tcl

I would like to execute the following query against an sqlite database:

```
set LCs [ DB eval { SELECT DISTINCT LC FROM   MyTable  WHERE LC IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) }  ]
```

This yields the desired result  1 3 4

Trying the follwing throws an syntax error:

set InString "1, 3, 4"

```
set LCs [ DB eval { SELECT DISTINCT LC FROM   MyTable  WHERE LC IN ( :InString ) } ]
```

I have used the **:Varaible** before without problems, but in this case it fails possible due to the braces. How can i use a TCL varibale in an SQLite IN statment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are needing to move a number of values into SQLite from Tcl in order to do this sort of thing, put them into a temporary table in the `:memory:` database first, then use SQL operations to pull them from there.

```
DB eval {
    ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS memdb;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE memdb.values (val TEXT);
}
foreach val {1 3 4} {
    DB eval {
        INSERT INTO memdb.values (val) VALUES (:val)
    }
}
set LCs [DB eval {
    SELECT DISTINCT LC FROM MyTable WHERE LC IN memdb.values.val
}]
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about `:memory:` until seeing your answer. Definitely something I'd consider using more from now on instead of going for temporary tables in the same database as the one I'm working on.

Comment: Using sqlite 3.21.0 I get:  near "values" :syntax error    when executing the create temp table statement although I do not see an formal error in the statement..

Comment: Following the tip given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459126/using-tcl-sqlite-syntax-error-when-creating-table-in-memory-temp-table  the suggested approch works.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs: "Tcl variable names can appear in the SQL statement [...] in any position where it is legal to put a string or number literal." So, you can do:

```
set LCs [DB eval {SELECT DISTINCT LC FROM MyTable WHERE LC IN (:v1, :v2, :v3)}]
```

but you can't use a variable for the complete list. Instead you either have to build the string before passing it to `DB eval`, or you create a function to perform the check whether the value is in the list.

Option #1:

```
set LCs [DB eval "SELECT DISTINCT LC FROM MyTable WHERE LC IN ($InString)"]
```

Option #2:

```
proc check {val} {
    global InString
    return [expr {$val in $InString}]
}
db function search check
set LCs [DB eval {SELECT LC FROM MyTable WHERE search(LC)}]
```

For option #2, $InString should be a normal Tcl list, so not comma separated.